# Find Index of an Object in a generic List in C#

Tags: c#, list, object, generics, indexing

I have a generic class

```
public class foo <T> where T:boo
{
  List<T> fooList;
}
```

Now there is a method of the foo class, which should return the index of an object of type boo.

```
public getIndex(boo booObject)
{
   int index = fooList.IndexOf(booObject);
}
```

Unfortunately this is not working, because booObject can't be converted to Type T...

How can I get the the index???
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change the type of `booObject` from `boo` to `T`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the type of your parameter `booObject` to the generic type T. This is because you defined that the type T is deriving form `boo`, but it still is not `boo`. That means, it could be some class `goo` deriving from `boo`. But then you'd try to get the index of an object of type `boo` out of a list of objects of type `goo` - which wouldn't make sense.

And furthermore you forgot the return type of your method and to actually return the evaluated index:

```
public class foo<T> where T : boo
{
    List<T> fooList;

    public int getIndex (T booObject)
    {
        int index = fooList.IndexOf (booObject);
        return index;
    }
}
```

For more information on generics have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/).